# How to download files using WinSCP command line?

Tags: command-line, winscp

I have created a .txt file and saved it as abc.txt. I'm trying to use this to download files from a remote server.

The contents of the said .txt file are:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open stfp://root:password@123.456.789.2/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa AA:BB:CC:12:22"
get %1%
exit
```

I'm trying to run this file via command prompt. So I've opened the `cmd` prompt, and enter commands as follows

```
cd  C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP

winscp E:\Ritesh\abc.txt /parameter // file.csv
```

`file.csv` being the remote file I want to download. However, this is not working. I can't figure out why. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the [`/script` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting):

```
winscp /script=E:\Ritesh\abc.txt /parameter // file.csv
```